# Loopback-4 Mocking injection

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback4, v4l2loopback

i'm using loopback-4, looking for help to mock the @inject declared at class level.

**Please find below code.**

```
import { repository } from '@loopback/repository';
import { AddressRepository } from './address.repository';
import { Address } from './address.db.model';

export class AddressService {
    @repository(AddressRepository) private addressRepo: AddressRepository;

    async getAddresses(): Promise<Address[]> {
      return this.addressRepo.find();
    }
}
```

i am trying to mock through **@loopback/testlab.StubbedInstanceWithSinonAccessor** but its not working, as i am not using constructor injection. tried with below approach but it wont allow.

```
let addressRepo: StubbedInstanceWithSinonAccessor<AddressRepository>;
const addressService = new AddressService(addressRepo);
```

can some one help in mocking @injector which is not declared at constructor level?

thank you in advance.

Comment: Where do you want `@inject` to be declared?  `@inject` can also be used in the properties of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your dependency is declared as a property, you need to provide the stubbed implementation via a property setter.

1. Make your property `public` so that it can be changed from outside.

   ```
   export class AddressService {
     @repository(AddressRepository) 
     public addressRepo: AddressRepository;

     // ...
   }
   ```
2. Use a regular property setter in your tests.

   ```
   let addressRepo: StubbedInstanceWithSinonAccessor<AddressRepository>;
   const addressService = new AddressService();
   addressService.addressRepo = addressRepo;
   ```